# Querying XML colum for values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with an XML column, and it contains data something like this:

```
<Query>
  <QueryGroup>
    <QueryRule>
      <Attribute>Integration</Attribute>
      <RuleOperator>8</RuleOperator>
      <Value />
      <Grouping>OrOperator</Grouping>
    </QueryRule>
    <QueryRule>
      <Attribute>Integration</Attribute>
      <RuleOperator>5</RuleOperator>
      <Value>None</Value>
      <Grouping>AndOperator</Grouping>
    </QueryRule>
  </QueryGroup>
</Query>
```

Each QueryRule will only have one Attribute, but each QueryGroup can have many QueryRules. Each Query can also have many QueryGroups.

I need to be able to pull all records that have one or more `QueryRule` with a certain attribute and value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM QueryBuilderQueries 
WHERE [the xml contains any value=X where the attribute is either Y or Z]
```

I've worked out how to check a specific QueryRule, but not "any".

```
SELECT
  Query
FROM
  QueryBuilderQueries
WHERE
  Query.value('(/Query/QueryGroup/QueryRule/Value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like 'UserToFind'
  AND Query.value('(/Query/QueryGroup/QueryRule/Attribute)[1]', 'varchar(max)') in ('FirstName', 'LastName')
```

Comment: it's still unclear on your XML data, each `QueryRule` may have more than 1 `Attribute` element?

Comment: I've expanded the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `exist()`. One to check the value and one to check Attribute.

```
select Q.Query
from dbo.QueryBuilderQueries as Q
where Q.Query.exist('/Query/QueryGroup/QueryRule/Value/text()[. = "UserToFind"]') = 1 and
      Q.Query.exist('/Query/QueryGroup/QueryRule/Attribute/text()[. = ("FirstName", "LastName")]') = 1
```

If you really want the `like` equivalence when you search for a Value you can use `contains()`.

```
select Q.Query
from dbo.QueryBuilderQueries as Q
where Q.Query.exist('/Query/QueryGroup/QueryRule/Value/text()[contains(., "UserToFind")]') = 1 and
      Q.Query.exist('/Query/QueryGroup/QueryRule/Attribute/text()[. = ("FirstName", "LastName")]') = 1
```

Comment: That's almost perfect. The only remaining problem is that the "UserToFind" needs to be a variable coming from elsewhere in the sproc, but I get an error that the parameter to exists needs to be string literal.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I used ``contains(., sql:variable("@test"))``, which seems to work.

Comment: @Cylindric Yes, that is the way to do it.

Comment: @Cylindric I post the answer here without really being sure if it works, so please make a confirmation about it. At least it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms178030%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

"The XQuery must return at most one value"

If you are quite certain that for example your XML has let's say maximum 10 QueryRules you could maybe use `WHILE` to loop everything while droping your results into temporary table?

maybe below can help you anyway

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
Query type)

DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 1
WHILE @i >= 10
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT
        Query
    FROM QueryBuilderQueries
    WHERE Query.value('(/Query/QueryGroup/QueryRule/Value)[@i]', 'varchar(max)') LIKE 'UserToFind'
    AND Query.value('(/Query/QueryGroup/QueryRule/Attribute)[@i]', 'varchar(max)') IN ('FirstName', 'LastName')

  @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT
    *
FROM #temp
```

Comment: Happy to change to an ``exists`` or whatever it takes. I don't really need the result, just to know there is one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pity that the SQL Server (I'm using 2008) does not support some XQuery functions related to string such as `fn:matches`, ... If it supported such functions, we could query right inside XQuery expression to determine if there is ***any***. However we still have another approach. That is by turning all the possible values into the corresponding SQL row to use the `WHERE` and `LIKE` features of SQL for searching/filtering. After some experiementing with the `nodes()` method (used on an XML data), I think it's the best choice to go:

```
select *
from QueryBuilderQueries 
where exists( select *
              from Query.nodes('//QueryRule') as v(x)
              where LOWER(v.x.value('(Attribute)[1]','varchar(max)')) 
                                          in ('firstname','lastname')
                    and v.x.value('(Value)[1]','varchar(max)') like 'UserToFind')
```